# Difference between getAnimatedValue() and getAnimatedFraction()

Tags: android, android-animation, viewanimator

Could anyone tell me the difference between the two methods `getAnimatedValue()` and `getAnimatedFraction()` used in android `ValueAnimator`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you mean getAnimatedValue() and getAnimatedFraction()?

getAnimatedValue() returns the current value for the variable you are animating.

getAnimatedFraction() returns the value that is used for animating (it always goes from 0.0 to 1.0 basically, and the linearity of it is set by the interpolator). The animatedValue is determined through this by multiplication.

Say you want to linearly animate from 0 to 100 in 10 seconds. On the 9th second, animatedFraction is 0.9f and the animatedValue is 100*0.9f = 90.

Comment: thanks @Travo, yes its getAnimatedValue()instead of getValueAnimator(). and thanks for that example. I used getAnimatedValue() but it was returning an Object, and when I used  getAnimatedFraction() it was returning  float datatype directly . Why are they having different datatypes.? Because of this i was unable to cast an object to float  in the case of **getAnimatedValue()**

Comment: Hey! The getAnimatedValue() does not know about its class type (except that it has to be extending Object). You have to cast it to what it is supposed to be manually. If you know you are animating float, you have to cast it into float: `float opacity = (float) animation.getAnimatedValue();`

Comment: Actuallly i had created a class of my own were i am extending **valueAnimator** in which i tried to cast  the value to float but i was  unable cast  the value from getAnimatedValue(). And here above the "animator" object is of which type ?

Comment: Mhh. Here's how I initiated my float animator, which returns an Object that is castable into Float from getAnimatedValue();
`ValueAnimator backgroundAlphaAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1f, 0f);`
To be honest, I am not so sure what you are asking right now.

Comment: kkI will elaborate it.This is how I tried to cast the Value  ....                .class AnimationSample extends **valueAnimator**  {                                 ...                                                                                                                                                                               float  particle=(float) getAnimatedValue();//   //showing "Unable to cast from        // object to float                                                                                                        ...}

Comment: You might need to cast it into Float (not the primitive type float). Try `Float particle = (Float) getAnimatedValue();`

Comment: Hey thanks ! Now working for me!! Thanks  a lot!! :-)